# Problems with Google Maps and jQuery accordion

Tags: jquery, google-maps, accordion

I'm having a problem, which was already described here, but I didn't find a way to solve it.
The problem is I'm using this jQuery snippet for accordion:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#accordion > li > div.ac-inner').click(function(){

if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
    $('#accordion ul').slideUp(300);
}
    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
});
    //$('#accordion ul:eq(0)').show()
});
```

And with this HTML I'm loading Google Map:

```
<ul id="accordion">
<li id="acc-1"><div class="ac-inner"><h3>Tab 1</h3></div>
    <ul>
        <li><div><!-- Map goes here --></div></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li id="acc-2"><div class="ac-inner"><h3>Tab 2</h3></div>
    <ul>
        <li><!-- Content goes here --></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li id="acc-3"><div class="ac-inner"><h3>Tab 3</h3></div>
    <ul>
        <li><!-- Content goes here --></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

This is my CSS:

```
#accordion {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
width: 527px;
}
#accordion li {
background: none;
padding-left: 0;
}
#accordion div.ac-inner {
display: block;
cursor: pointer;
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding: 0 7px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
background: #F5F5F5; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FAFAFA 0%, #F5F5F5 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#FAFAFA), color-stop(100%,#F5F5F5)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FAFAFA 0%, #F5F5F5 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FAFAFA 0%, #F5F5F5 100%);/* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #FAFAFA 0%,#F5F5F5 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(top,  #FAFAFA 0%,#F5F5F5 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#FAFAFA', endColorstr='#F5F5F5',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff inset;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff inset;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
-moz-text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
-webkit-text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
}
#accordion ul {
list-style: none;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
#accordion ul {
display: none;
}
#accordion ul li {
font-weight: normal;
cursor: auto;
background-color: #fff;
padding: 0 0 0 7px;
}

#accordion a {
text-decoration: none;
}
#accordion a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}
#accordion #acc-1 div.ac-inner {
background: url(../images/icons/map.png) no-repeat 0 0 #F5F5F5;
text-indent: 70px;
}
#accordion #acc-2 div.ac-inner{
background: url(../images/icons/calendar.png) no-repeat 0 0 #F5F5F5;
text-indent: 70px;
}
#accordion #acc-3 div.ac-inner {
background: url(../images/icons/camera.png) no-repeat 0 0 #F5F5F5;
text-indent: 70px;
}
```

Google says this is a problem because of the CSS rule display: none; so the map is rendered partially (with grey blocks over) and is not centered.

Is it possible just to adapt upper jQuery snippet to get this thing working or would I have to touch Google Map loading script (which is loaded dynamically through CMS plugin)?

Comment: is it OK to show the first tab on load? http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/AXZuj/ seems to work fine with the default map frame. I haven't tried with the scripts, though.

Comment: Here I pasted exact HTML output GMaps plugin gives me: http://jsfiddle.net/esedic/AXZuj/3/

As you can see in that case map in the first tab is not rendered correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is described in the [jQuery UI Tabs faq](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#...my_slider.2C_Google_Map.2C_sIFR_etc._not_work_when_placed_in_a_hidden_.28inactive.29_tab.3F) as well. Try listening to the accordion change event and triggering a map refresh with

```
 google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, Rick! Could you write an example how could I achieve this with the script I'm using? You can see it here:  jsfiddle.net/esedic/AXZuj/3

Comment: Are you referencing map tiles directly? I don't see a reference to the API anywhere.

Comment: I saw your comment from above on gmap output. Since the method to resize is a API call, you're going to have to grab the map object from gmap plugin and call it. Having the direct markup from gmap won't help at all.

Answer (score 2):

If you are embedding an iframe in an accordion, then refreshing the src of the iframe when opening the panel worked for me:

```
$(".theaccordion" ).accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    collapsible:    true,
    activate    :   function(e,ui) {
        ui.newPanel.find('iframe').each(function() {
            $(this).get(0).src = $(this).attr('src');
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$(".theaccordion" ).accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    collapsible:    true,
    activate    :   function(e,ui) {
        ui.newPanel.find('iframe').each(function() {
            $(this).get(0).src = $(this).attr('src');
        });
    }
});

This worked for me. Thanks Mitch McCoy